# Transmit datastring using SIM7600 4G hat

Tags: communication

I've been using Adafruit Fona with SIM800 chip to transmit data through the phoneline. SIM800 is a 2G chip but this network is closed in Norway so now I bought a Waveshare SIM7600 hat for Arduino instead. When using Fona I set up the call with this command: "ATDphonenumber" and when the connection was established I got this message: "CONNECT 9600". Then Fona went into data mode and I could send and receive datastrings before returning to command mode using +++. On the SIM7600 I need to write the call-command this way: "ATDphonenumber;" and the respond is "BEGIN: VOICE CALL" when connection is established. The problem is I can't get into datamode. The manual says use this AT command: "ATO" but that gives me "NO CARRIER" in return.
Now I wonder how I can make a call to another device and be able to send datastrings just like using Fona.

Comment: LTE doesn't have a "data mode". It's a direct internet connection. Set up the APN for your carrier and start a session, then you can make TCP and UDP connections directly.

Comment: OK, that makes it all more clear. I will check out that. Thank you so much for your reply!